# Axios request not working with React Native + Nodejs

Tags: node.js, react-native, axios

Trying to make the SignIn function work along with NodeJS backend. On clicking the Signin button nothing is happening, with an error appearing on console saying -- POST http://IP_Address:3000/signin net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

```
import api from "../services/api";

const signIn =
  (dispatch) =>
  async ({ email, password }) => {
    try {
      const response = await api.post("/signin", { email, password });
      await AsyncStorage.setItem("token", response.data.token);
      dispatch({ type: "sign_up_in", payload: response.data.token });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      dispatch({
        type: "add_error",
        payload: "Something went wrong with Sign In",
      });
    }
  };

Here is what is residing inside the services/api.js
import axios from "axios";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";

axios.defaults.baseURL = "http://IP_Address:3000";

const instance = axios.create();

instance.interceptors.request.use(
  async (config) => {
    const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem("token");
    if (token) {
      config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
    }
    return config;
  },
  (err) => {
    return Promise.reject(err);
  }
);

export default instance;
```

Comment: Have you verified if your API is up and running on PORT 3000?

Comment: Yes I have been running the node server on my CMD, while the client( react-native) on my VS Code Terminal.

Comment: So, your api base url `"http://IP_Address:3000"` is `"http://localhost:3000"` or `"http://127.0.0.1:3000"` right ?